# Kafka Streams not sending records to output topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Application that is receiving records to an input topic doing some stream processing on it and sending processed records to multiple output topics. It was running perfectly fine until I stopped it.

After stopping the first Streams app, I created a different streams application that has different input and output topic.

Next, I started both applications and my second application worked perfect but my first application has stopped doing any processing at all.

When I start a console-consumer on input topics I can see records being produced, but when I start console-consumer on output topics I am not receiving any records. I don't what could have gone wrong. I thought may be its because of the second streams application. So I stopped it and recreated all the topics and restarted the first application again but its still not doing anything.

Note: I am doing this on a local server.

Next I build the streams application on my personal machine and its working as expected.

What could have gone wrong that I am seeing this unexpectedly strange behavior?

Here is my code:

**Main Class:**

```
public class Pipe {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Pipe.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

    log.info("Starting application");

    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String BROKER_URL = env.get("BROKER_URL");


    String appId = "98aff1c5-7a69-46b7-899c-186851054b43";
    String appSecret = "zVyS/V694ffWe99QpCvYqE1sqeqLo36uuvTL8gmZV0A=";
    String appTenant = "2f6cb1a6-ecb8-4578-b680-bf84ded07ff4";

    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092"); // pass from env localhost:9092 | BROKER_URL + ":9092"
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


    log.info("Creating stream: o365_storage");
    KStream<String, String> source_o365_storage = builder.stream("o365_storage");

    log.info("Creating stream: scan_result_dlp");
    KStream<String, String> source_scan_result_dlp = builder.stream("scan_result_dlp");

    log.info("Creating stream: scan_result_malware");
    KStream<String, String> source_scan_result_malware = builder.stream("scan_result_malware");

    log.info("Creating stream: source_o365_user_contenturl");
    //KStream<String, String> source_o365_contenturl = builder.stream("o365_activity_contenturl");
    KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_contenturl = builder.stream("o365_activity_contenturl");

    log.info("Creating stream: source_o365_contenturl_result");
    KStream<String, String> source_o365_contenturl_result = source_o365_user_contenturl.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
            try {
                String accessToken = O365Util.getAccessToken(appId, appSecret, appTenant);

                System.out.println("accessToken : " + accessToken);

                System.out.println("Creating futures..");
                List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
                JSONArray contentUrlList = new JSONArray(value);
                for (int i = 0; i < contentUrlList.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject contentUri = contentUrlList.getJSONObject(i);
                    //futures.add(executor.submit(new FetchLogService(accessToken, contentUri.getString("contentUri"))));
                    futures.add(executor.submit(new FetchLogService(accessToken, contentUri, appTenant)));
                }

                System.out.println("futures size is : " +  futures.size());
                for (Future<?> f : futures) {
                    if (f.get() != null) {
                        //System.out.println("Executing contentUri parallel....................... ");
                        String futureResult = f.get().toString();
                        if (String.valueOf(futureResult.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("[")) {
                            //System.out.println("futureResult is JSONArray");
                            JSONArray logList =  new JSONArray(futureResult);
                            for (int k = 0; k < logList.length(); k++) {
                                JSONObject log = logList.getJSONObject(k);
                                //System.out.println("Added logs into Events for action : " + log.getString("Operation"));
                                keywords.add(log.toString());
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("futureResult is JSONObject");
                            JSONObject contentUrlObj = new JSONObject(futureResult);
                            keywords.add(contentUrlObj.toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("future result is nullllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll");
                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                executor.shutdownNow();
            }

            return keywords;
        }
    });

    log.info("Creating stream: source_o365_user_activity_intermediate");
    KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_activity_intermediate = source_o365_contenturl_result.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                if (value.contains("Operation\":")) {
                    keywords.add(value);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return keywords;
        }
    });

    source_o365_user_activity_intermediate.to("o365_user_activity");

    log.info("Creating stream: o365_contenturls");
    KStream<String, String> o365_contenturls = source_o365_contenturl_result.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                if (value.contains("contentUri\":")) {
                    keywords.add("["+value+"]");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return keywords;
        }
    });

    o365_contenturls.to("o365_activity_contenturl");


    log.info("Creating stream: o365_user_activity");
    KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_activity = builder.stream("o365_user_activity");

    log.info("Creating branch: branches_source_o365_user_activity");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KStream<String, String>[] branches_source_o365_user_activity = source_o365_user_activity.branch(
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"SharingSet") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")),        // Sharing Set by Date
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"AddedToSecureLink") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")), // Added to secure link
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"AddedToGroup")),                                             // Added to group
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"Add member to role.") || value.contains("Operation\":\"Remove member from role.")),//Role update by date
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileUploaded") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileDeleted")
                    || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileRenamed") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileMoved")),       // Upload file by date
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"UserLoggedIn")),                                             // User logged in by date
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"Delete user.") || value.contains("Operation\":\"Add user.")
                    && value.contains("ResultStatus\":\"success"))                                                      // Manage user by date
            );

    log.info("Creating branch: branches1_source_o365_user_activity");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KStream<String, String>[] branches1_source_o365_user_activity = source_o365_user_activity.branch(
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileUploaded") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileModified") 
                    || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileDeleted")),                                                    // File update by date
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileAccessed"))                                              // File access by date
            );

    log.info("Creating branch: branches2_source_o365_user_activity");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KStream<String, String>[] branches2_source_o365_user_activity = source_o365_user_activity.branch(
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileUploaded") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileModified")
                    || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileDeleted") || value.contains("Operation\":\"SharingSet") 
                    && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File"))                                                             // File operation by date
            );

    log.info("Creating branch: branches3_source_o365_user_activity");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KStream<String, String>[] branches3_source_o365_user_activity = source_o365_user_activity.branch(
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Workload\":\"AzureActiveDirectory") || value.contains("Workload\":\"OneDrive") || value.contains("Workload\":\"SharePoint")) // Activity log by date
            );

    log.info("Creating branch: branches4_source_o365_user_activity");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KStream<String, String>[] branches4_source_o365_user_activity = source_o365_user_activity.branch(
            (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileUploaded") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileModified"))  // Download file for scanning
            );

    /////////////////////////////////=========================  DLP LOGS ========================/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(source_scan_result_dlp, Constant.O365_GTB_BREACHED_POLICY_BY_DATE, "o365_gtb_dlp_breached_policy_by_date");

    //////////////////////////////////////==================== MALWARE LOGS ================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(source_scan_result_malware, Constant.O365_LAST_LINE_MALWARE, "o365_last_line_malware");

    //////////////////////////////////////==================== ALL LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(source_o365_user_activity, Constant.O365_USER_ACTIVITY_BY_DATE, "o365_user_activity_by_date");

    ////////////////////////////////////====================== STORAGE LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(source_o365_storage, Constant.O365_STORAGE_BY_DATE, "o365_storage_by_date");

    //////////////////////////////////////==================== BRANCH LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[0], Constant.O365_SHARING_SET_BY_DATE, "o365_sharing_set_by_date", Constant.O365_SHARING_SET_BY_DATE_EXCEP_KEYS);
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[1], Constant.O365_ADDED_TO_SECURE_LINK_BY_DATE, "o365_added_to_secure_link_by_date");
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[2], Constant.O365_ADDED_TO_GROUP_BY_DATE, "o365_added_to_group_by_date");
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[3], Constant.O365_ROLE_UPDATE_BY_DATE, "o365_role_update_by_date");
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[4], Constant.O365_UPLOAD_FILE_BY_DATE, "o365_upload_file_by_date", Constant.O365_UPLOAD_FILE_BY_DATE_EXCEP_KEYS);
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[5], Constant.O365_USER_LOGGED_IN_BY_DATE, "o365_user_logged_in_by_date");
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_o365_user_activity[6], Constant.O365_MANAGE_USER_BY_DATE, "o365_manage_user_by_date");

    ////////////////////////////////////====================== BRANCH 1 LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches1_source_o365_user_activity[0], Constant.O365_FILE_UPDATE_BY_DATE, "o365_file_update_by_date");
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches1_source_o365_user_activity[1], Constant.O365_FILE_ACCESS_BY_DATE, "o365_file_access_by_date");

    ////////////////////////////////////====================== BRANCH 2 LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches2_source_o365_user_activity[0], Constant.O365_FILE_OPERATION_BY_DATE, "o365_file_operation_by_date");

    ////////////////////////////////////====================== BRANCH 3 LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches3_source_o365_user_activity[0], Constant.O365_ACTIVITY_LOG_BY_DATE, "o365_activity_log_by_date");

    ////////////////////////////////////====================== BRANCH 4 LOGS ====================================////////////////////////////////////////////
    branches4_source_o365_user_activity[0].to("download_file_for_scanning");



    final Topology topology = builder.build();
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.trace("Exiting application.");
            streams.close();
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    try {
        streams.start();
        latch.await();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

**AppUtil:**

```
public final class AppUtil {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Pipe.class.getName());

public static HashMap createHashMap(String[] keys, String[] values) {
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        hmap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
    }

    return hmap;
}

public static void pushToTopic(KStream<String, String> sourceTopic, HashMap<String, String> hmap, String destTopicName) {
    log.info(destTopicName+ " inside function");
    System.out.println(destTopicName + " inside function");

    sourceTopic.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {

            log.info("================================================================================================================================================================================");
            log.info("========> " + destTopicName + " Log:\n \n" + value);
            System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================================================");
            System.out.println("========> " + destTopicName + " Log:\n \n" + value);
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject received = processJSON(new JSONObject(value), destTopicName);


                send.put("current_date", getCurrentDate().toString());
                if (!destTopicName.equals("o365_storage_by_date")) {
                    send.put("insertion_time", getCurrentDateTime().toString());
                }
                boolean valid_json = true;
                for(String key: hmap.keySet()) {
                    if (received.has(hmap.get(key))) {
                        send.put(key, received.get(hmap.get(key)));
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("\n \n Missing Key in JSON: Cannot send log to destination topic = " + destTopicName + " | " + hmap.get(key) + " Key is missing.");
                        log.error("\n \n Missing Key in JSON: Cannot send log to destination topic = " + destTopicName + " | " + hmap.get(key) + " Key is missing.");
                        valid_json = false;
                    }
                }   
                if (valid_json) {
                    keywords.add(send.toString());  
                }
                // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                log.error("Unable to convert to json");
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return keywords;
        }
    }).to(destTopicName);
}
//////////////////////////////////////

public static void pushToTopic(KStream<String, String> sourceTopic, HashMap<String, String> hmap, String destTopicName, String[] exceptionalKeys) {

    sourceTopic.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {

            log.info("================================================================================================================================================================================");
            log.info("========> " + destTopicName + " Log:\n \n" + value);
            System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================================================");
            System.out.println("========> " + destTopicName + " Log:\n \n" + value);
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject received = processJSON(new JSONObject(value), destTopicName);


                send.put("current_date", getCurrentDate().toString());
                if (!destTopicName.equals("o365_storage_by_date")) {
                    send.put("insertion_time", getCurrentDateTime().toString());
                }
                boolean valid_json = true;
                for(String key: hmap.keySet()) {
                    if (received.has(hmap.get(key))) {
                        send.put(key, received.get(hmap.get(key)));
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("\n \n Missing Key in JSON: Sending log to destination topic = " + destTopicName + " with null value | " + hmap.get(key) + " Key is missing.");
                        log.warn("\n \n Missing Key in JSON: Sending log to destination topic = " + destTopicName + " with null value | " + hmap.get(key) + " Key is missing.");

                        if(!isExceptionalKey(exceptionalKeys, hmap.get(key))) {
                            valid_json = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (valid_json) {
                    keywords.add(send.toString());  
                }
                // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                log.error("Unable to convert to json");
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return keywords;
        }


    }).to(destTopicName);
}
//////////////////////////////////////
private static boolean isExceptionalKey(String[] exceptionalKeys, String currKey) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean isExceptionalKey = false;

    for (String string : exceptionalKeys) {
        if (string.equals(currKey)) {
            isExceptionalKey = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isExceptionalKey;
}
public static JSONObject processJSON(JSONObject jsonObj, String destTopicName) {
    if (jsonObj.has("UserId")) {
        String val = jsonObj.get("UserId").toString().toLowerCase();
        jsonObj.remove("UserId");
        jsonObj.put("UserId", val);
    }
    if (jsonObj.has("TargetUserOrGroupName")) {
        String val = jsonObj.get("TargetUserOrGroupName").toString().toLowerCase();
        jsonObj.remove("TargetUserOrGroupName");
        jsonObj.put("TargetUserOrGroupName", val);
    }
    if (jsonObj.has("ObjectId")) {
        String val = jsonObj.get("ObjectId").toString().toLowerCase();
        jsonObj.remove("ObjectId");
        jsonObj.put("ObjectId", val);
    }
    if (jsonObj.has("EventData")) {
        String val = jsonObj.get("EventData").toString().toLowerCase();
        jsonObj.remove("EventData");
        jsonObj.put("EventData", val);
    }
    if (destTopicName.equals("o365_last_line_malware")) {
        jsonObj.put("MaliciousScore", "-1");
    }
    if (destTopicName.equals("o365_activity_log_by_date") || destTopicName.equals("o365_gtb_dlp_breached_policy_by_date")) {
        jsonObj.put("ActivityDetail", jsonObj.toString());
    }
    return jsonObj;
}
public static String getCurrentDate() {

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String UTCdate = dateFormat.format(date);
    return UTCdate;
}

private static String getCurrentDateTime() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
    return datetime;
}
```

}

Comment: Wow, that's a big piece of code. It must be very hard to debug like this. Couple of tips: you can still invoke methods from lambdas and methods inside a kafka stream, and putting the bulk of the code in normal, properly deconstructed, methods is a good idea. Second, flatMapValues is not the only operation that exists on a KStream. A lot of what you do can be a simple filter: `source_o365_user_activity_intermediate = source_o365_contenturl_result.filter(v -> v.contains("Operation\":"));` for example.

Comment: To find out which step breaks your pipeline(s), I'd remove components until it works again, and then add components one by one until it breaks, then you know where the problem is. Catching all exceptions and only printing them isn't helping, better to throw it on to let the pipeline fail, unless you have a way in which you can handle the exception.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Actually the thing is that the exact same piece of code is working fine on my local machine. And I have just rebooted the server and started everything again and the streams app seems to be working as nothing had happened.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the tips. I know I should really refactor my code. But Its really boggling my mind that why would it stop working just like that and for no apparent reason.

Comment: Did you use different application ids for the applications? Kafka-streams uses the application id as the consumer group, and read offsets are kept for each consumer group. If you used the same application.id then one application may have consumed messages that the other won't see anymore (if there is an overlap in the input topic)

Comment: I have use separate ids. Moreover, both applications have different topics